# ChartJs events in Angular

Tags: angular, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm making a chart where I need to click on each data label (I point this out in the image below) to then display the specific charts of the data that was clicked.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIaO9.png)

My problem is that I cannot click and identify which data label I am pressing, I know I am using the getElementsAtEvent method from ChartJs, but using the bound data in Angular I cannot access this method (I am not creating a chart object). I share my code below:

**My template:**

```
<div style="display: block">
<canvas id ="radarChart" baseChart [datasets]="radarChartData" [labels]="radarChartLabels"
    [chartType]="radarChartType" [options]="radarChartOptions"></canvas>
```

**My component:**

```
export class GraficoRadarComponent implements OnInit {

  public radarChartLabels = [];
  public radarChartData = [{
    label: '',
    data: [],
    hidden: false,
  },
  ];

  public radarChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 4,
        stepSize: 1,
      },
      pointLabels: {
        fontSize: 15,
      }
    },
    legend: {
      onHover:this.chartClickEvent,
      position: 'right',
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'black',
        fontSize: 15,
      },
    }
  };
  public radarChartType = 'radar';

  chartClickEvent(event, array) {
    console.log(event)
   };
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm throwing this response together piece-meal from a working solution in a module I just wrote. This particular offering hasn't been fully tested, but the crux of it is here exactly as it was working in my code.
I put my final working code together using bits of code from stackoverflow, but nothing I found looks quite like this code does (using ViewChild and Angular click event wire-up), so my working solution is somewhat unique and IMHO much simpler & straightforward.

NOTE: So long as the ViewChild canvas reference becomes a chart reference at runtime, I think the code is sound. My working solution created the chart object in the TypeScript code where yours is created in HTML, so I had a direct reference to the chart object where this code attempts to use the ViewChild reference.

If not, you may need to add a let statement to the event code to pull the chart object from the canvas reference (something like `let myChartObj = this.myChartCanvas.(chartProperty);`) and then reference myChartObj in place of this.myChart in the event code)

**TEMPLATE**

(I added #chartCanvas and (click) event)

```html
<div style="display: block">
<canvas #chartCanvas (click)="onChartClick($event)" id="radarChart" baseChart [datasets]="radarChartData" [labels]="radarChartLabels"
    [chartType]="radarChartType" [options]="radarChartOptions"></canvas>
```

**COMPONENT CODE**

Add to your imports:

```js
import { Chart, ChartElement } from 'chart.js';
```

Add to your class variables:

```js
@ViewChild('chartCanvas') myChart;
```

Your event handler:

```js
onChartClick(event) {
  let ActivePoints: ChartElement[] = this.myChart.getElementsAtEvent(event);
  // to do - check ActivePoints for undefined, return if true
  let idx = ActivePoints[0]['_index'];
  let lbl: string = this.myChart.data.labels[idx];
  let dat = this.myChart.data.datasets[0].data[idx];
  console.log(lbl,dat);
}
```